# how to stop stream clustering on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, storage, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, high-availability

I have a Postgresql database with some databases in it. The databases are working well, and I backup them daily. I decided to make a cluster from it and make it available if the main system goes down to the other node (cluster responses to the queries). My main server had 490 GB of storage. The databases used just 40% of this space.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnLtn.jpg)

I made a streaming cluster using the guidance of "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fv2t1a4G2o&t=16s" this video.

The cluster didn't work when I shut down the main server, and the secondary server didn't respond to queries, so I removed the second server.

**The main problem is that after this, the main server storage grows very fast.**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCNvl.jpg)

I just extended the storage size for a temporary solution to this problem.

How can I bring the server to time before clustering without losing data???